# pass parameters in URL code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI and would normally try to pass some information back to a login page like the following...

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model', '', true);

    if ($this->User_model->authenticate($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password')))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', true);
        header('Location: /');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: /sessions/login/error?='.'1');
    }
}
```

And then on the login page use a _GET.

So how would I best go about this in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Have you done any research into it yourself?

Comment: hmm.. im not really understanding what you are asking. What information are you trying to pass to the login page? is it the results you got from your Authenticate method? if so, why not set the information in your session as you are doing with 'loggedin'?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using GET for sensitive data like email/password is a general no-no. Bad practice all the way.

But the answer to your question is here - http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html

`$this->input->get('username')` is equal to `$_GET['username']`. 
You might use `$this->input->get('username', TRUE)` to escape some malicious code.

And `$this->input->post('username')` is equal to `$_POST['username']`. This is what I advise you to use (it requires modification of your HTML though)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you want to pass `_GET` variables for the error codes, right? as i see you are using `_POST` variables for the form as you should.

As you are working with Codeigniter, you can use the URI structure of the framework and instead of working with `_GET` work with the MVC structure.

So, instead of redirecting this:

```
header('Location: /sessions/login/error?='.'1');
```

Redirect like this:

```
header('Location: /sessions/login/error/1');
```

Then in your controller for the login, in the error method:

```
function error($msgId = 0) {
  // here you will get the number you sent in the url as $msgId
}
```

If you still need to work with `_GET` variables, that is possible as well. go to the main application config file of the framework `/aplication/config/config.php` and have a look on the `Enable Query Strings` section